# Add a fixed amount to all file-modified dates (date arithmetic on the command line)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I've a year of photos in a folder, but I never set the date on my new camera. How do I add a fixed interval to correct the file modified date for all files in a folder? Would this be a job for powershell ?

Comment: Yes. But keep in mind that the file date/time is not the meta data inside the picture (Exif/IPTC). There are a mass of tools to do this more comfortably then scripting. (XNView/Exifer/IrfanView/...)

Comment: Please note the [tag:batch-file] tag does not mean processing multiple files, instead it is another kind of MS script. But I'm not sure which meaning do you mean.

Comment: @LotPings I can't see anything that does this in IrfanView? Exifer is dead since 2002. I don't know much about command line, but I'm aware of the difference between dos, powershell and batch files. The question maybe should have been "how do you do date arithmetic on the command line?"

Comment: Well, I just listed from memory. See [this Q&A on photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27245/is-there-a-free-program-to-batch-change-photo-files-date-to-match-exif) For date calculations in batch see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41037011/6811411)

Comment: @LotPings thanks. Reading through the photo.stackoverflow link, it turns out Picasa has exactly the functionality I need, perhaps because accurate dates are really important for Picasa's chronological ordering. Details [here](https://www.scanyourentirelife.com/picasa-change-date-photo-taken-digital-camera-scanned-photo/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instinct to use powershell is a very good one :-) Date arithmetic in CMD is [a nightmare](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#Yesterday), but in powershell [it's very easy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/21/adding-and-subtracting-dates-with-powershell/). This powershell script did the business.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\sby\Pictures\small squares" | 
Foreach-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime.AddDays(7)    
}
```